# Не выводится в консоли объект с данными геолокации

Tags: javascript

```
window.onload = function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        alert ("Geolocation is not supported by this browser");
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  var coords =  "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat="+latitude+"&lon="+longitude;
  return coords;
}

function Get(yourUrl){
    var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    Httpreq.open("GET",yourUrl,false);
    Httpreq.send(null);
    return Httpreq.responseText;          
}

var json_obj = JSON.parse(Get(coords));

console.log(json_obj);
```

Comment: а что происходит?

Comment: вообще ничего. Нет записей в консоли. Если я правильно понимаю логику: получаем данные геолокации при загрузке окна -> передаем их в функцию showPosition, которая возвращает стринг (ссылку, содержащую данные долготы и широты) -> через json.obj преобразуем json с указанной ссылки в объект. Или я не прав?

Comment: `coords` - локальная переменная в `showPosition`. Откуда она берется в строке `var json_obj = JSON.parse(Get(coords));`?

Comment: да уж... базовые знания хромают